# Could not open file /usr/var/lib/couchdb/test.couch: no such file or directory; even the file is physically present

Tags: couchdb

I am using Apache CouchDB 1.6.1 on Debian 8.4 machine. Sometimes CouchDB logs that Could not open file /usr/var/lib/couchdb/test.couch: no such file or directory; even the file is physically present. Can anyone help?

Comment: Here are some details that might help. What were you trying to do with this happened? Have you used couchdb on this machine before? If not, how did you install couchdb? What are the permissions on the file test.couch?

Comment: In my system there are many process accessing couchdb via curl. There is chances of high rate of reading and writing by processes. As I told it is happening in in running condition i.e. starting it access normally without fail but after sometime it start to fail read/write of particular(randomly) .couch file while other .couch file database access properly.

Comment: couchdb user is owner of every couch files and all files have read/write permissions. couchdb is running as a service and couchdb is user of this service. When I got this issue I have tested many time that after rebooting the system couchdb again starts working properly. I am not changing any permissions of couch files. Actually database is mounted on SSD SATA hence at time of creating SATA partition for database, ownership and permission is set as per required.